# DVD authoring software that supports multiple angles?

Tags: windows, dvd

I'm writing a DVD ripping app and I need to get some sources with multiple angles. Unfortunately, they seem to be rather hard to come by. I figured my best bet would be to author a simple DVD with a multi-angle title.

Does anyone know of any software on Windows that lets you make multi-angle titles? Preferably free or trialware? I don't need it to be super-usable, just enough to make one DVD.

Answer (score 1):

[**DVD lab pro**](http://www.mediachance.com/dvdlab/)  supports Multiple Angles/BOV

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps explain how to do it as well @Joshua?

Comment: It does indeed have a multiple angles feature. However I've had a heck of a time just trying to get it to output a multi-angle DVD that's not corrupted. It seems to be quite picky about what input files you give it.